# error in database connection when upload laravel on sharedhost

Tags: laravel-5, voyager

[image]i have a project (laravel + voyager + passport) it is work perfect on localhost, but when deploy to sharedhost (Hostinger), i faced this error when try to access (voyager login page):

```
"SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'osama_mis-user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (View: /home1/osama/public_html/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/login.blade.php)
```

and i am sure is my information in (.env) is right

i also delete config.php file from bootstrap/cache but still faced this problem?

Comment: Are you make `.env` ??

Comment: yes of course i do